# Mysql connection is not established with localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

In services i have an issue like this
[image]
Also when i tried installing mysqld in command prompt i am facing the below issue.[image]

my server config is as follows
[image][image][image]
software installed are as follows
[image]
please let me know where i am going wrong
enter image description here

[image][image]

```
[![enter image description here][9]][9]
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8I4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check any other service is not running on the same port on which MySQL is trying to run.

By default, MySQL runs on 3306 port.
And if you want to change this port number you can by editing in my.ini file in MySQL folder.

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server\

```
    # The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
    port=3306 //try to change this
```

Comment: how do i check if some one else is using the same port?

Comment: also i dont find my.ini anywhere in my system

Comment: send the screenshot of your mysql folder

Comment: please see the initial query posted.I have added the images.please let me know if u need some other info

Comment: Also please note i am not able to install MySQL router

Comment: I am facing some issue with some dll while installing it

Comment: my.ini file will be in MySQL server 5.7 folder send me a screenshot of that folder

Comment: I donthave my.ini exactly.i included all the mysql related folders and screenshot is also attached with the first post

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i6MwY7t6eeWPlexlOgBo4FE1OT2odqlx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: above path has al ini files that are in mysql folder